# How to handle a "Error establishing a database connection"?

Tags: errors

For a little project i am using WP by loading

```
require( '../site/wp-load.php');
```

When the local msyql server is running everything works great. But in certain situations the local mysql server isn't running or the password isn't correct and the Response Header reads
 `Error establishing a database connection`

How can i catch this error and output a custom message as the frontend of this project looks like it's running ok?

Comment: Check this question: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37828/is-there-a-plugin-that-will-override-the-error-establishing-a-database-connecti/37829#37829

Comment: tx rob for the link